# Running python2.6 selftest.py gives me this error

Tags: python, django, macos, python-imaging-library

> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'selftest.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

When I do which python I get /opt/local/bin/python

So the selftest.py is looking in the wrong place but how would I fix this?

The python manage.py shell works and all the other django commands.

I'm running this selftest.py after installing PIL

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      darwin 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Aug  8 2010, 21:45:26)
          [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
library, and set the corresponding ROOT variable in the
setup.py script.

To check the build, run the selftest.py script.
running build_scripts
creating build/scripts-2.6
copying and adjusting Scripts/pilconvert.py -> build/scripts-2.6
copying and adjusting Scripts/pildriver.py -> build/scripts-2.6
copying and adjusting Scripts/pilfile.py -> build/scripts-2.6
copying Scripts/pilfont.py -> build/scripts-2.6
copying and adjusting Scripts/pilprint.py -> build/scripts-2.6
changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/pilconvert.py from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/pildriver.py from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/pilfile.py from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/pilfont.py from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/pilprint.py from 644 to 755
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what is going on without more information, like exactly what you typed and the contents of the `selftest`.py file.  But a more important question is: why are you going to the trouble of installing PIL from scratch?  From the the paths you show (`/opt/local/`) you are apparently already using `MacPorts`.  You can have a working, up-to-date PIL installed with two commands (one, if you keep your `MacPorts` installation up-to-date):

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
$ sudo port py26-pil
```

You can also install django from `MacPorts`:

```
$ sudo port py26-django
```